# Using a for loop to count not the length of a list but to count the characters of the strings in the list?

Tags: python-3.x

Having some trouble with loops so been practicing. Here is my current code

```
def total_length(strings):
    for word_count in strings:
        word_count = len(strings)
    return word_count
        
print (total_length(["aa","bb","cc"]))
```

This will give me 3 since there's 3 strings in the argument. But how would I go about using len() to count the total characters in the list?

Comment: In `for word_count in strings`, the name `word_count` refers to each individual string in the list. It's not an integer that represents the number of items in the list, it's _one of these items_.

Comment: Ok that makes sense.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
def total_length(strings):
    word_count = 0
    for word in strings:
        word_count += len(word)
    return word_count
```

Comment: If I'm reading this correctly, the variable word goes through the list strings and then I'm getting the length of each string then adding that to my word count variable?

Comment: The variable word is a temporary variable which is assigned to each string in the list of strings. For example, strings = ['aa', 'bb', 'cc']; word will be equal to first 'aa', then 'bb', then 'cc'. word_count is a variable initialized to 0 and will have each word's length added to it.

Comment: Thank you! Wrapping my head around the temporary variable is what's been tripping me up. Again much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

```
def total_length(strings):
    word_count = sum(len(i) for i in strings)
    return word_count

print (total_length(["aa","bb","cc"]))
```

Or you can directly do:

```
strings = ["aa","bb","cc"]
sum(len(i) for i in strings)
```

Both Outputs:

```
6
```